# Why pandas.DataFrame.join is not doing what I expect?

Tags: python, pandas

I have one data frame `inverters` which looks like this:

```
                        Voltage (ADCu)
Time (ps) n_TDC signal                
0         0     INV[0]            1404
                INV[0]            1403
                INV[0]            1403
                INV[0]            1404
                INV[0]            1403
...                                ...
5990      2     INV[8]            1182
                INV[8]            1181
                INV[8]            1181
                INV[8]            1174
                INV[8]            1192
```

Now I have the following code:

```
_ = inverters['Voltage (ADCu)'] - inverters.groupby(['n_TDC','signal']).min()['Voltage (ADCu)']
_ = _ / _.groupby(['n_TDC','signal']).max()
_.name = 'Voltage (normalized)'
_ = _.to_frame()
_ = _.reset_index(drop=False).set_index(inverters.index.names).sort_index()
print(_)
inverters = inverters.join(_)
print(inverters)
```

which prints

```
                        Voltage (normalized)
Time (ps) n_TDC signal                      
0         0     INV[0]              0.996522
                INV[0]              0.994783
                INV[0]              0.994783
                INV[0]              0.996522
                INV[0]              0.994783
...                                      ...
5990      2     INV[8]              0.511062
                INV[8]              0.509956
                INV[8]              0.509956
                INV[8]              0.502212
                INV[8]              0.522124

[269973 rows x 1 columns]
                        Voltage (ADCu)  Voltage (normalized)
Time (ps) n_TDC signal                                      
0         0     INV[0]            1404              0.996522
                INV[0]            1404              0.994783
                INV[0]            1404              0.994783
                INV[0]            1404              0.996522
                INV[0]            1404              0.994783
...                                ...                   ...
5990      2     INV[8]            1192              0.511062
                INV[8]            1192              0.509956
                INV[8]            1192              0.509956
                INV[8]            1192              0.502212
                INV[8]            1192              0.522124

[4502709 rows x 2 columns]
```

I don't understand why the last print does not have 269973 rows. What is going on? The two data frames in the call to `join` have literally the same index... Even if I add `_.index = inverters.index` right before the call to `join` I get the same result.

What I want to do is the obvious horizontal concatenation matching by index value, i.e. just append `_` to the right of `inverters`.

Comment: Better provide a [mre] (as code), your current example is difficult to reproduce

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting all the extra rows because your index is not unique, so every row in `inverters` gets joined to every row in `_` which has the same index. For your requirements, you can simply use `concat` instead:

```py
inverters = pd.concat([inverters, _], axis=1)
```

Alternatively you can make the assignment to the column directly:

```py
g = inverters.groupby(['n_TDC', 'signal'])['Voltage (ADCu)']
inverters['Voltage (normalized)'] = g.transform(lambda g:(g - g.min()) / max(g - g.min()))
```

For your sample data, the result is the same for either method:

```
                        Voltage (ADCu)  Voltage (normalized)
Time (ps) n_TDC signal
0         0     INV[0]            1404              1.000000
                INV[0]            1403              0.000000
                INV[0]            1403              0.000000
                INV[0]            1404              1.000000
                INV[0]            1403              0.000000
5990      2     INV[8]            1182              0.444444
                INV[8]            1181              0.388889
                INV[8]            1181              0.388889
                INV[8]            1174              0.000000
                INV[8]            1192              1.000000
```

Comment: `inverters.groupby(['n_TDC', 'signal'])['Voltage (ADCu)']` fails, but the other option is doing what I want.

Comment: @user171780 in what way does it fail?

Answer (score 1):

> What is going on? The two data frames in the call to join have literally the same index

Yes but the index is not unique so `join` like `merge` give you the cross product. As your dataframe have the same length, I think you can simply use:

```
inverters['Voltage (normalized)'] = _['Voltage (normalized)']
print(inverters)

# Output
                        Voltage (ADCu)  Voltage (normalized)
Time (ps) n_TDC signal                                      
0         0     INV[0]            1404              1.000000
                INV[0]            1403              0.000000
                INV[0]            1403              0.000000
                INV[0]            1404              1.000000
                INV[0]            1403              0.000000
5990      2     INV[8]            1182              0.444444
                INV[8]            1181              0.388889
                INV[8]            1181              0.388889
                INV[8]            1174              0.000000
                INV[8]            1192              1.000000
```

Comment: This one does not work, it actually raises `ValueError: cannot handle a non-unique multi-index!`.